# PostMessage get iframe value

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, postmessage

I have two servers ( for example: `localhost:3000` and `http://example.com` ).
In the localhost, I have an iframe that is connected to `http://example.com` ( through src attribute ), so I've sawed a lot of answers that showed how to get data, but I didn't saw any that showed how to save it.

```html
<!-- localhost:3000 -->
<iframe src="http://example.com" id="example"></iframe>

<script>
  let iframeCONTENT = null;
  // ^^^^ how do I fill this variable with the content of iframe
  
  let iframe = document.querySelector("#example");
  let iframeDocument = iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentDocument;
  
  iframeDocument.postMessage("", "*")
</script>

<!-- http://example.com -->

 <h1>Hello World!</h1>
 <p>Blabla!</p>

<script>
    window.addEventListener("message", (e) => {
       console.log(document.body)
    }, false)
</script>
```

Comment: the iframe needs to send a postMessage back with the contents. ANd the first page needs to listen for that.

Comment: @epascarello, how do I do it? I've wrote  `window.addEventListener("message", e: any => console.log(e.data), false)` on the localhost, but it throwed an error `Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('http://localhost:3000') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://example.com')`